# Is $x \mapsto \sqrt{2|x| - x^2}$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $x \mapsto \sqrt{2|x| - x^2}$ differentiable at $0$? Intuitively, it looks to me like it should be, since the limit of the tangent lines from the left and right are both vertical lines. However, this intuition contradicts a theorem from my analysis textbook (*An Introduction to Analysis* by W. Wade):

> **4.2 Theorem.** A real function $f$ is differentiable at some point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there exist an open interval $I$ and a function $F : I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\in I$, $f$ is defined on $I$, $F$ is continuous at $a$, and
>
> $$f(x) = F(x)(x-a)+f(a)$$
>
> holds for all $x\in I$, in which case $F(a) = f'(a)$.

Is this one of those cases where different people take different definitions?

Comment: Yes, it is this case...but it's easy to show all those "different" definitions are actually equaivalent.

Comment: You should write out a proof using this theorem and defitnion of differentiation.

Comment: I just realized I asked the wrong question--I meant for a different function. Should I edit this question or make a new one?

Comment: @Red: Make a new one. Someone might already be answering this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac{\sqrt{2|x|-x^2}-0}{x}=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\frac{2}{x}-1}&,\;\;\;x>0\\{}\\-\sqrt{-\frac{2}{x}-1}&,\;\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

One is the definition of right derivative and the other of the left derivative at $\,x=0\,$ . Can you see why the function cannot be differentiable at that point?......

Comment: Take $f(x) = \sqrt{2|x|-x^2}$. Then $f(x)/x \xrightarrow{h \to 0^-} -\infty$ and $f(x)/x \xrightarrow{h \to 0^+} +\infty$.

Comment: Well, in fact both limits are infinite since the square root of a real number's always non-negative, but basically you're on the right path.

Comment: The $x<0$ case should have a minus sign out front, I think.

Comment: I don't think so, since we need the whole expression $\,(-x)\,$ to be able to introduce it into the square root: $$x<0\Longrightarrow -x>0\Longrightarrow \frac{\sqrt A}{-x}=\sqrt{\frac{A}{x^2}}$$ Note that in the last expression the minus sign vanishes.

Comment: But $\frac{\sqrt{2|-1|-(-1)^2}}{-1} = -1$

Comment: Yes @Red...so?? You take a positive ($\,1\,$) and change its sign $\,-1\,$, and I took a negative $\,x<0\,$ and changed its sign $\,-x\,$ to make it *positive*!

Comment: Sorry if I'm being frustrating, but I'm still convinced there should be another minus sign outside of the square root in the $x<0$ case: For $x=-1$, the left hand side comes out to $-1$ but the right hand side comes out to $1$.

Comment: I don't think I can help you anymore with this, @Red : obviously I can't reach you to make you understand something this basic. You may want to post a new question about this specific question, perhaps someone else will explain it to you better than I do.

Comment: I think red is right, the left and right expressions in your equation are not the same, the one on the left is negative if x<0, the one on the right is always positive

Comment: actually, you forgot to leave a minus sign outside of the square root when you put a negative value inside. The function is the top of two circumferences of centers x=-1 and x=1 tangent at x=0 , so the left derivative is actually $-\infty$

Comment: @DonAntonio: "You may want to post a new question about this specific question[...]" -- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340108/does-this-equality-hold

Comment: I obviously misunderstood Red: I thought he meant a minus sign in fron of the original expression, like taking negative real number requires the sign. I forgot, apparently, to put the minus sign in front *of the square root* expression on the right of the braces. If this was the problem then yes, he's right, since $\,x<0 \iff -x>0\,$ , so $$\frac{\sqrt{2|x|-x^2}}{x}=-\frac{\sqrt{2|x|-x^2}}{-x}=-\sqrt{-2/x - {1}}\ldots$$

Comment: No worries! I should have made an edit like julian did, so there wouldn't have been any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the graphic approach. Look first at the radicand, $2|x|-x^2$, whose graph in the neighborhood of the origin has the familiar $\vee$-shape, with slopes $\mp2$. What happens when you take square root of such a function? You get the shape $\prec$, but turn this so the cusp points downwards. Unquestionably nondifferentiable. (Or is that nonquestionably undifferentiable?)